# Map function with setTimeout doesn't return JSX element

Tags: css, jsx, settimeout, map-function

I was thinking if it's any possibility to create animated buttons using setTimeout on map elements.
I am learning React Transition group and i've created this code:

```
function NavItemSub(props) {

  const array1 = props.array1;
  return (
    <ul className="gallery-menu" >
      <TransitionGroup className="todo-list"
        component={null}>{array1.map((e, index) => (
          <SwitchTransition>
            <CSSTransition
              key={index}
              in={true}
              timeout={1000}
              classNames="item"
              appear={true}
            >
              <li key={index} className="item">
                <a href="#" className="icon-button-sub">{props.icon}{e}</a>
              </li>
            </CSSTransition>
          </SwitchTransition>
        ))}
      </TransitionGroup>
    </ul>
  )
}
```

The effect is that the buttons appear in the same time.I want the buttons entered one by one. I've tried add setTimeout function on loop and it's working with some simple console.log but it's not returning JSX element.
Thanx for help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
timeout={index * 1000}
```